# Getting 404 for an external Javascript file in HTML on XAMPP

Tags: javascript, html, xampp, worker

This is my first post on Stackoverflow. Please guide if I miss something.
I'm trying to do HTML5 development with external javascript file and testing the same on XAMPP 3.2.1 server.
I have stored "HF_Chapter10_WebWorkers_Example1" in "C:\xampp\htdocs" of XAMPP installation and the Javascript file "manager.js" is also residing in the same folder. The 'manager.js' internally creates a worker thread and invokes the same.

Issue: When I'm opening the HTML file in Google Chrome, I see 404 (in Dev chrome tools) stating the server can't find the external Javascript file referenced. Also, I see that the server is load the javascript file as 'text/HTML' instead of 'text/javascript'. I have tried appending type='text/javascript' in the call to the javascript but that didn't help either.
 I'm trying to understand the reason of this issue.

This is what goes into the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Wed, 08 Jan 2014 05:07:11 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>HF_Chapter10_WebWork_Example1</title>

    <LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="theme.css" TYPE="text/css"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="manager.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="output"> ![enter image description here][1]</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what goes into the javascript file 'manager.js'

```
window.onload = function() {
    //create the worker thread
    var worker = new Worker("worker.js");

    //send the message to the worker thread
    worker.postMessage("ping");

    //create an event listener to act on the messages arriving from the worker thread
    worker.onmessage = function(event) {
        var message = "Worker says" + event.data;
        document.getElementById("p").innerhHTML = message;
    }
}
```

This is what goes into the worker.js file:

```
onmessage = pingPong;
function pingPong(event) {

    //based on the type of data, respond back with the 'postMessage'.
    //Note that the message will go to the main javascript handler
    if (event.data == "ping") {
        postMessage("pong");
    }
}
```

Comment: give me the screenshot of your folder structure

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. Any ideas on the solution?

Comment: how do you run this file , just double clicking on it?

Comment: When I open the [link](https://localhost/xampp/) in chrome, it opens the XAMPP control panel. 
So, I use below URL [link](https://localhost/HF_Chapter10_WebWorkers_Example1.html) to execute my HTML file in Chrome:

Comment: can you put HF_Chapter10_WebWorkers_Example1.html, manager.js in seperate folder named test and run using http://localhost/test/ and run and check for the same 404 issue in chrome dev tools

Comment: The problem is solved. I figured out that the javascript file was named as "manager.js.js" and hence couldn't be found when loading the HTML. The issue happened in the first place, because Windows 7 doesn't show the file extension by default. After correcting the javascript file, the 404 error got resolved. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

not clear what generates the 404 but this might help you
http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_example_htdocs.html

I am attaching the image of the folder structure.
[image: Here's the image of the folder structure]